# Override emojis from EditText and summon these emojis from my android app

Tags: android

I noticed that google added an emoji shortcut in the keyboard *(Probably was in there a long time ago, but I just noticed it:) )*. I'm trying to disable emojis shortcut from the keyboard and summon these same emojis from an icon that I add in my app. Is it doable?

**For example:** The Facebook Messenger app has an independent icon button just for emoji, so my idea to use an independent button but with the already provided emojis from Google.

So far, I added my independent imageView icon, which is clickable, but I'm trying to make this icon summon Google emojis if this last can be overridden.

Answer (score 1):

First, add this attribute to Edittext

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
```

This is how I disable the emojis on the keyboard

```
public class EmojiExcludeEditText extends EditText {
    public EmojiExcludeEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public EmojiExcludeEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public EmojiExcludeEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        setFilters(new InputFilter[]{emojiExcludeFilter});
    }

    @Override
    public void setFilters(InputFilter[] filters) {
        if (filters.length != 0) { //if length == 0 it will here return when init() is called
            boolean add = true;
            for (InputFilter inputFilter : filters) {
                if (inputFilter == emojiExcludeFilter) {
                    add = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (add) {
                filters = Arrays.copyOf(filters, filters.length + 1);
                filters[filters.length - 1] = emojiExcludeFilter;
            }
        }
        super.setFilters(filters);
    }

    private EmojiExcludeFilter emojiExcludeFilter = new EmojiExcludeFilter();

    private class EmojiExcludeFilter implements InputFilter {

        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
            for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
                int type = Character.getType(source.charAt(i));
                if (type == Character.SURROGATE || type == Character.OTHER_SYMBOL) {
                    return "";
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I saw this posted already before opening my thread. Can these same Emojis be called from an independent icon or button within the app?